# Asp.net Mvc JqGrid column with jqMultiSelect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an issue about **jqgrid**. Im using mvc version of jqgrid. Im setting a simple dropdown column like this;

```
public static void SetUpDropDownColumn(JQGrid jqGrid, string columnName)
{
    JQGridColumn dropDownColumn = jqGrid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == columnName);
    dropDownColumn.Editable = true;
    dropDownColumn.EditType = EditType.DropDown;

    if (jqGrid.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData)
    {
        Array enumArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitsType));
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>(enumArray.Length);

        foreach (var i in enumArray)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(UnitsType), i),
                Value = i.ToString()
            });
        }
        dropDownColumn.EditList = items;
    }
}
```

But I want to add some extra properties to this dropdown. like multiselect with autocomplete.
I searched and found jqMultiSelect.

How can I impliment `jqMultiSelect` to jqgrid columns? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that building **jqgrid** in javascript and then `select2` plugin with `multiselect`.